# SSRS: Getting "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Good afternoon, SO.

I'm trying to put my working SSMS query into SSRS, and I'm getting the mentioned error. I've looked over the code and I'm not seeing a multiple call, and so I came to you guys for help. I know it's long, and am more than willing to answer any questioned needed. I'm so lost.

Basically I need an overly convoluted join string (ugh, this program is going to be the bane of my existence). To gain provider data into the temp table I have to create (no physical way of making this without that)

```
/*  These 2 below SELECTs pull the Group provider data only from Acuity which is output to #Temp_Group table */

SELECT DISTINCT provider.provider_identity 
      ,provider_affiliation.db_record_id_parent
      ,provider_affiliation.db_record_id_child 
      ,provider.external_provider_id 
      ,provider.npi 
      ,provider.provider_name 
      ,provider.provider_type 
      ,provider.tax_id
      , db_record_parent.db_record_id
INTO #Temp
FROM provider AS provider 
    ,provider AS provider2 
    ,provider_affiliation 
    ,db_record AS db_record_parent 
    ,db_record AS db_record_child 
WHERE (( provider.provider_identity = db_record_parent.key1 ) 
  AND  ( db_record_parent.db_record_id = provider_affiliation.db_record_id_parent ) 
  AND  ( provider2.provider_identity = db_record_child.key1 ) 
  AND  ( db_record_child.db_record_id = provider_affiliation.db_record_id_child ) 
  AND  (provider.provider_type = 'G') 
  AND  (db_record_parent.table_code = 'PROV') 
  AND  (provider2.provider_type <> 'G') 
  AND  (db_record_child.table_code = 'PROV'))
  AND  provider.status = 'ACTV'

SELECT t.provider_identity
      ,t.db_record_id_parent
      ,t.db_record_id_child
      ,t.NPI
      ,t.provider_name
      ,t.provider_type
      ,dbo.address.address_1 AS [Billing Address]
      ,dbo.address.address_2 AS [Billing Suite]
      ,dbo.address.city AS [Billing City]
      ,dbo.state.state_code AS [Billing State]
      ,SUBSTRING(dbo.address.zip,1,5) AS [Billing ZIP] 
      ,(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', dbo.address.zip ) = 0
             THEN ''
             ELSE SUBSTRING(dbo.address.zip,(CHARINDEX('-', dbo.address.zip ) + 1),4)
         END) AS [Billing ZIP Extension]
      ,dbo.telephony.telephony_string AS [Billing Phone]
      ,fax_tele.telephony_string AS [Billing Fax]
INTO #Temp_Group
FROM #Temp AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.address_link 
             ON t.db_record_id = dbo.address_link.db_record_id 
            AND dbo.address_link.order_no = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.address 
             ON dbo.address_link.address_identity = dbo.address.address_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.db_record AS dbr_addr 
             ON dbo.address.address_identity = dbr_addr.key1 
            AND dbr_addr.table_code = 'ADDR' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.state 
             ON dbo.address.state_identity = dbo.state.state_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony_link 
             ON t.db_record_id = dbo.telephony_link.db_record_id 
            AND dbo.telephony_link.order_no = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony 
             ON dbo.telephony_link.telephony_identity = dbo.telephony.telephony_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.reason_reference AS rr_fax 
             ON rr_fax.reason_code = 'FAX' 
            AND rr_fax.reason_type = 'TT' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony_link AS fax_tell 
             ON t.db_record_id = fax_tell.db_record_id 
            AND fax_tell.telephony_type_identity = rr_fax.reason_reference_identity 
            AND fax_tell.order_no = (SELECT  MIN(order_no) AS Expr1
                                       FROM  dbo.telephony_link AS fl
                                       WHERE (db_record_id = t.db_record_id) 
                                         AND (telephony_type_identity = rr_fax.reason_reference_identity)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony AS fax_tele 
             ON fax_tell.telephony_identity = fax_tele.telephony_identity 

/* Final Query that combines the provider and group records on the same row.  This query is to provide Aetna a provider list of MP(Master Plan) plans */

SELECT  DISTINCT dbo.person_name.last_name AS [Last Name], dbo.person_name.first_name AS [First Name], dbo.person_name.middle_name AS [Middle Name], CAST(dbo.person.birthdate AS DATE) AS DOB, dbo.person.sex AS Gender, dbo.person_name.name_suffix AS [Degree 1]
       ,NULL AS [Degree 2], NULL AS [Degree 3] 
       ,(CASE WHEN tax.description = '' OR tax.description IS NULL
                   THEN tax.description
              WHEN tax.description IN ('General Practice','General Dentist','Dentist')
                   THEN 'PCP'
              ELSE 'Specialist'
          END) AS Role
       ,tax.description AS [Specialty 1]

       ,(CASE WHEN udf.user_field_data_14 > ' ' AND udf.user_field_data_14 <> 'NA'
             THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
          END) AS [Board Cert]
       ,NULL AS [Effective Date]
       ,REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), udf.user_field_data_15, 101), '/', '') AS [Expiration Date]
       ,udf.user_field_data_14 AS [Specialty 1 Board Name]
       ,NULL AS [Specialty 2], NULL AS [Board Cert (Y/N)], NULL AS [Effective Date], NULL AS [Expiration Date], NULL AS [Specialty 2 Board Name]
       ,NULL AS [Specialty 3], NULL AS [Board Cert (Y/N)], NULL AS [Effective Date], NULL AS [Expiration Date], NULL AS [Specialty 3 Board Name]
       ,(CASE WHEN rr_l.description <> 'English'
              THEN rr_l.description
              ELSE NULL
          END) AS Language
       ,NULL AS [Medical School], NULL AS [Grad Year]
       ,udf.user_field_data_10 AS [Medicare #], NULL AS [Medicare Exp Date]
       ,REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), udf.user_field_data_30, 101), '/', '') AS [CDS Exp Date]
       ,udf.user_field_data_13 AS [CDS Number]
       ,udf.user_field_data_12 AS DEA, REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), udf.user_field_data_18, 101), '/', '') AS [DEA Exp]
       ,COALESCE(vpl.state,NULL) AS [License State of Issue]
       ,udf.user_field_data_11 AS [State Lic #], REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), udf.user_field_data_17, 101), '/', '') AS [State Lic Exp]
       ,udf.user_field_data_09 AS [Medicaid #],NULL AS [Medicaid Expiration Date],NULL AS [Medicaid State]
       ,NULL AS [Public Email], dbo.telephony.telephony_string AS [NPI Phone Number], dbo.provider.NPI AS [NPI Number (Type 1)]
       --,COALESCE(vppa.privilege_provider1_name, NULL) AS [Hospital Affiliation Name 1] 
       ,vppa.privilege_provider1_name AS [Hospital Affiliation Name 1] 
       ,NULL AS [Hospital Affiliation Name 2]
       ,NULL AS [Hospital Affiliation Name 3]
       ,dbo.person_id_key.id_key AS SSN, dbo.provider.tax_id, NULL AS [TIN Owner], dbo.provider.provider_name AS [Group Name]

       ,t2.NPI AS [NPI Number (Type II)]  
       ,'' AS [Does this NPI apply to all Service Locations and Billing Addresses for this Tax id?]
       ,'' AS [Does this NPI apply to all providers using this Tax id?]
       ,'' AS [Does this NPI apply to all Service Locations and Billing Addresses for this provider only?]
       ,'' AS [Does this NPI apply to all to all tax ids for this provider only?]
       ,dbo.address.address_1 AS [Service Address],dbo.address.address_2 AS [Service Suite],dbo.address.city AS [Service City], dbo.state.state_code AS [Service State],  SUBSTRING(dbo.address.zip,1,5) AS [Service ZIP] 

       ,(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', dbo.address.zip ) = 0
             THEN ''
             ELSE SUBSTRING(dbo.address.zip,(CHARINDEX('-', dbo.address.zip ) + 1),4)
         END) AS [Service ZIP Extension]
       ,dbo.telephony.telephony_string AS [Service Phone], fax_tele.telephony_string AS [Service Fax]
       ,(udf.user_field_data_01 + '|' + udf.user_field_data_02 + '|' + udf.user_field_data_03 + '|' + udf.user_field_data_04 + '|' + udf.user_field_data_05 + '|' + udf.user_field_data_06 + '|' + udf.user_field_data_07) AS [Office Hours]
       ,NULL AS [Practice Age Limitations]


       ,udf2.user_field_data_03 AS [Accepting New Patients]
       ,udf2.user_field_data_02 AS [Directory Print]

       ,t2.[Billing Address]
       ,t2.[Billing Suite]
       ,t2.[Billing City]
       ,t2.[Billing State]
       ,t2.[Billing ZIP] 
       ,t2.[Billing ZIP Extension]
       ,t2.[Billing Phone]
       ,t2.[Billing Fax]

       ,REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), dbo.address_link.start_date, 101), '/', '')  AS [Network TIN/Service Location Effective Date]
       ,REPLACE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), dbo.address_link.end_date, 101), '/', '') AS [Network TIN/Service Location Term Date]
       ,CAST(udf.user_field_data_26 AS DATE) AS [Original Credential Date]
       ,CAST(udf.user_field_data_27 AS DATE) AS [Recredential Date]

       ,(CASE WHEN udf.user_field_data_21 = udf.user_field_data_26
             THEN ''
             ELSE  CAST(udf.user_field_data_21 AS DATE)
         END) AS [Most Recent Recredentialing Date] 
       ,NULL AS [PEARL-HAMP Provider?]


       ,company.company_code 
       ,company.description



       ,dbo.address.additional_loc
       ,dbr_addr.db_record_id AS db_record_id_addr
       ,dbo.provider.external_provider_id,  dbo.db_record.active_flag,dbo.provider.provider_type

       ,dbo.provider.provider_identity

       ,db_record.db_record_id
       ,db_record.key1
       ,db_record.linking_id
       ,db_record.record_template_library_identity
       ,db_record.calling_db_record_id
       ,db_record.parent_db_record_id

       ,t2.db_record_id_parent
       ,t2.provider_identity

FROM    dbo.provider 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.db_record 
             ON dbo.provider.provider_identity = dbo.db_record.key1 
            AND dbo.db_record.table_code = 'PROV' 

-- For Group provider data (Billing Address fields) joining to a regular Provider record
LEFT OUTER JOIN [#Temp_Group] AS t2
             ON t2.db_record_id_child = dbo.db_record.db_record_id

-- Next 3 Joins needed to access company.company_code and to pull MP records (Dental Master Plan)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.provider_affiliation praf
             ON praf.db_record_id_child = dbo.db_record.db_record_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.db_record AS dbr_parent 
             ON praf.db_record_id_parent = dbr_parent.db_record_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN company 
             ON dbr_parent.key1 = company.company_identity 

-- For 'Accepting New Patients' and 'Directory Print' Flags code (Found on the Provider Network tab in Acuity)           
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_provider_network_affiliation vpna
             ON vpna.key2 = dbo.provider.provider_identity
            AND vpna.key1 = '280'
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_field_data AS udf2
             ON udf2.table_code='PRNW' 
            AND udf2.key1=vpna.provider_affiliation_identity 


--Service Address fields (Regular provider records level)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.address_link 
             ON dbo.db_record.db_record_id = dbo.address_link.db_record_id 
            AND dbo.address_link.order_no = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.address 
             ON dbo.address_link.address_identity = dbo.address.address_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.db_record AS dbr_addr 
             ON dbo.address.address_identity = dbr_addr.key1 
            AND dbr_addr.table_code = 'ADDR' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.state 
             ON dbo.address.state_identity = dbo.state.state_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.reason_reference AS rr_country 
             ON dbo.address.country_identity = rr_country.reason_reference_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.reason_reference AS rr_region 
             ON dbo.address.region_identity = rr_region.reason_reference_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony_link 
             ON dbo.db_record.db_record_id = dbo.telephony_link.db_record_id 
            AND dbo.telephony_link.order_no = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony 
             ON dbo.telephony_link.telephony_identity = dbo.telephony.telephony_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.reason_reference AS rr_fax 
             ON rr_fax.reason_code = 'FAX' 
            AND rr_fax.reason_type = 'TT' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony_link AS fax_tell 
             ON dbo.db_record.db_record_id = fax_tell.db_record_id 
            AND fax_tell.telephony_type_identity = rr_fax.reason_reference_identity 
            AND fax_tell.order_no = (SELECT  MIN(order_no) AS Expr1
                                       FROM  dbo.telephony_link AS fl
                                       WHERE (db_record_id = dbo.db_record.db_record_id) 
                                         AND (telephony_type_identity = rr_fax.reason_reference_identity)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.telephony AS fax_tele 
             ON fax_tell.telephony_identity = fax_tele.telephony_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.reason_reference AS rr_telephony 
             ON dbo.telephony_link.telephony_type_identity = rr_telephony.reason_reference_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.provider_language 
             ON dbo.provider_language.provider_identity = dbo.provider.provider_identity 
            AND dbo.provider_language.order_no = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.users AS u_entry 
             ON dbo.provider.entry_by = u_entry.user_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.users AS u_mod 
             ON dbo.provider.mod_by = u_mod.user_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.reason_reference AS rr_l 
             ON dbo.provider_language.language_identity = rr_l.reason_reference_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.person_name 
             ON dbo.provider.person_identity = dbo.person_name.person_identity 
            AND dbo.person_name.order_no = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.person 
             ON dbo.person.person_identity = dbo.provider.person_identity 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.person_id_key 
             ON dbo.person_id_key.person_identity = dbo.person.person_identity 
            AND dbo.person_id_key.order_no = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.id_key_type 
             ON dbo.id_key_type.id_key_type_identity = dbo.person_id_key.id_key_type_identity
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.user_field_data udf 
             ON provider.provider_identity = udf.key1 
            AND udf.table_code = 'PROV'
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.provider_taxonomy prvt 
             ON prvt.provider_identity = dbo.provider.provider_identity
INNER JOIN dbo.taxonomy tax 
        ON tax.taxonomy_identity = prvt.taxonomy_identity

-- For Hospital Affil. Name
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_provider_privilege_affiliation AS vppa
             ON vppa.provider2_identity = dbo.provider.provider_identity

-- For License State of Issue
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_provider_license AS vpl
             ON vpl.provider_identity = dbo.provider.provider_identity




WHERE dbo.db_record.active_flag = 'Y'
    AND company.company_code in ('Prestige', '114', '115', '148', '181')

ORDER BY dbo.provider.NPI
```

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you have at least 3 [Expiration Date] fields. Although the third looks like it may just be a copy & paste mistake. Probably  would be easier to find your duplicate keys with a bit better formatting... that may save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jacob said, you have multiple fields with the same name: [Effective Date], [Board Cert (Y/N)]. While SSMS can handle this if you run the query, SSRS must have uniquely named columns so it knows what to put into each field of the report. One thing I started doing is putting the alias first, so instead of

```
dbr_addr.db_record_id AS db_record_id_addr
```

I would put

```
db_record_id_addr = dbr_addr.db_record_id
```

That nicely lines up all of the column names so they're easy to see.

Comment: Does the table prefix effect this as well?

Comment: No, the name must be unique: the prefix just tells the query where to get the data. That's why the query will work in SSMS but not SSRS.